# Output video to HDMI without creating a window with imshow?

Tags: opencv, hdmi

I have created an object detection, identification, and tracking application that runs and an NVIDIA Jetson TX2. The Jetson is mounted on a drone. The processed video from the application needs to be sent to the HDMI port which is connected to a digital radio that displays the video on a controller. I have spent some time looking at how to do this and have not been able to find any materials or examples on the subject. Is this possible?

Comment: you can directly write the image data to the framebuffer of the hdmi output in your linux. I can't tell you how to do it, but you will find the information in SO or by google.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will look.

Comment: I have sort of solved my issue by passing frames from OpenCV to streamed.